# Insert blank lines in jdom2 pretty printing

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jdom-2

I'm trying to simply add some blank lines to my jdom xml output.  I've tried the following without luck:

```
Element root = new Element("root");
root.addContent(new CDATA("\n"));
root.addContent(new Text("\n"));
```

I figured the all-whitespace entry was being ignored so I tried creating my own XMLOutputProccessor like this:

```
class TweakedOutputProcessor extends AbstractXMLOutputProcessor {
    @Override
    public void process(java.io.Writer out, Format format, Text text) throws IOException {
        if ("\n".equals(text.getText())) {
            out.write("\n");
        } else {
            super.process(out, format, text);
        }
    }
}\
```

... called like this:

```
public static void printDocument(Document doc) {
    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(new TweakedOutputProcessor());
    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    try {
            xmlOutput.output(doc, System.out);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

The unexpected thing here was that `process(..., Text)` was never called.  After some experimentation I've found that `process(..., Document)` is being called, but none of the other `process(..., *)` methods are.

I also tried overriding the `printText(...)` and `printCDATA(...)` methods, but neither is being called -- even when the text is non-whitespace!  Yet `printElement(...)` *is* being called.

So...

- What is going on here? What's doing the work if not these methods?

  How do I simply insert a blank line?

Answer (score 1):

Use the XML `xml:space="preserve"` when setting values in the XML. JDOM honours that [XML white space handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-white-space)

Comment: Thanks @rolfl for the tip.  So I tried `root.setAttribute("space", "preserve", Namespace.XML_NAMESPACE);`, which did indeed honor the blank lines, but it removed all Pretty-Printing formatting as well.  Is there a way to get both?  E.g. <root>\n  \t<element>\n  \t<element>\n  \n  \t<element>\n </root>  (does that make sense?)